# Laravel app improvement through caching

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I've built a fairly complex blogging system with Laravel.

Now when I have some traffic, I'm facing performance problems, some comes from the backend (Laravel).

I am using Redis for Caching and have some questions concerning Caching techniques with Laravel.

1. How would you cache main page posts pagination if at all?

   ```
   $posts = Post::trending()->
   with('user', 'blog', 'comments', 'likes')->paginate($paginate);
   ```
2. How about Caching Model Relations?
3. If not caching model relations, wouldn't it be smarter attaching the User / Blog / comments / likes of each post .from the cache?

Any tips and tricks are welcome! :)

Comment: 1. [refer this](https://laracasts.com/forum/?p=53-how-to-cache-paginated-query-with-key/0);2. chaces can store anything, try `::with` and store it to cache, it'll be retained - but it won't reflect updates unless explicitly updated; 3. that depends, if you had high number of get requests and slow database update it might possible, otherwise not. read up the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/cache) and hope someone else enlighten you on this.

Comment: 1. thanks! :) 2. I asked bout caching the returned relation from the model.